# Templating a Jinja2 CSR conf with all hostnames in SAN

Tags: ansible, openssl, jinja2

I have 3 servers in my Ansible inventory:

```
[hosts]
ServerA ansible_host=hostname1.domain ...
ServerB ansible_host=hostname2.domain ...
ServerC ansible_host=hostname3.domain ...
```

I want to generate CSR with all hostnames in subject alternative name and sometime ago, I heard about Jinja templating so I thought it would be nice to prepare template and get dynamically list of hostnames from Ansible. Can someone help me and tell how can I search for ansible_host in Jinja template? Can I use magic variables?

So my CSR configuration looks like:

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions = req_ext
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
emailAddress = email@address.com
C            = US
O            = Google
OU           = HR
CN           = {{ AppNameDns }}
[req_ext]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1=hostname1.domain
DNS.2=hostname2.domain
DNS.3=hostname3.domain
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, with the special variable [`groups`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) you can list all hosts of a specific group, and with the special variable `hostvars` you can access variables of those hosts.

You can also use [the special variables of the loop](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for) in Jinja to create for the index.

So the end of your configuration file end up being:

```
[alt_names]
{% for alt_host in groups['hosts'] %}
DNS.{{ loop.index }}={{ hostvars[alt_host].ansible_host }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I was trying to do it in different way but your code solved all my problems, thank you! :)